# MFMailComposeViewController navigation bar buttons are disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, sendmail

I use MFMailComposeViewController to send mail in my app. But when present mail compose view controller, all of navigation buttons are disabled (except back button in select mail address screen), i must use Home button to quit app. Does anyone has idea?
Here is screen shot:
[image: Screen shot]
[image: 2]

Code:

```
- (void)shareVieEmail
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setSubject:@"Test subject"];
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Mail message body" isHTML:NO];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photourl];
        [mailViewController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"example_photo"];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot send mail" message:@"Device is unable to send email in its current state" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}
```

Delegate method :

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            //NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            //NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail Sent Successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail Sent Failed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
            break;
        default:
            //NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    if (error) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot send mail" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR:%@", [error userInfo]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And in header file, I declared implement MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: can you show the code used to present the controller?

Comment: strange, it looks fine. Could it have something to do with you email settings? Does it look like this on all devices?

Comment: @mvds, it happened on both simulator and device. Sample project of Apple worked fine.

Comment: Are you aware that you are leaking an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` every time you present one? Could be problematic if the first instance somehow holds a lock of some kind, preventing a second instance to acquire one. Add a line `[mailer autorelease];` somewhere, remove app and reinstall.

Comment: At moment, I using ARC support to compile project (no need autorelease, retain,.. while coding), I thinks it isn't root cause. However, I'll try compile only this file with no ARC support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. and it took me a while to figure this out but no surprise it came down to customized UIBarButtonItem

I bet in your UIBarButtonItem.h there is a method

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled ;
```

and the implementation looks like this:

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    if (self.customView) {
        if ([[self.customView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])         {
            ((UIButton*)[self.customView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).enabled = enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is causing problem so as soon as you comment out this method your problem should go away.

Comment: Yeah! ^^. You right!, thank you!. I'll rewrite this method. This problem has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In your MFMailComposeViewController's delegate you need to implement `didFinishWithResult:` and dismiss the modal view controller from there.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{ 
    // you can test the result of the mail sending here if you want

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**For swift 4.0+**

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I implemented didFinishWithResult delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but it my case it was because I had overridden `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` from `UINavigationController` as proposed in this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289350/381233) for a bug in `CNContactViewController`. One solution that would still include the workaround and solve the problem in `MFMailComposeViewController` would be to use method swizzling to be able to call either the original method or the overridden one, depending on the class of the current `topViewController`.