# UINavigationBar system type buttons are disabled

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I use UINavigationController for my view controller. In init() or viewDidLoad(), i set :

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
   target:self action:@selector(selector)];
```

While present or push view, right bar button (and left if have) is disabled. But if I replace by custom button then it's worked normally.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
   initWithImage:image title:nil 
   target:self action:@selector(selector)];
```

I think this is root cause of my other question here :
[MFMailComposeViewController navigation bar buttons are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860736/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-navigation-bar-buttons-are-disabled)

Does anyone has ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to enable the edit button item is:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Does this also occur with other `UIBarButtonItemSystemItem`s ?

Comment: Yes!, It occur with every UIBarButtonItemSystemItem type button.

Comment: self.editButtonItem is one of solutions (using custom button can resolved), but in case of MFMailComposeViewController still unused.