# CNContactViewController hide navigationbar after contactImage fullscreenView

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I display contact detail page from my application using following code

```
let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forContact: Contact)
            unkvc.contactStore = CNContactStore()
            unkvc.delegate = self
            unkvc.allowsActions = true
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unkvc, animated: true)
```

Where `Contact` is `CNContact`'s object

When its push `unkvc` controller its show navigation bar its show navigationbar with back button and default edit button on right side.
but if contact has image and when i click on image its show fullscreen image but its hide navigation bar when back from image there is no navigation bar so i have no option to go back in my application page. so how to prevent it from hiding navigationbar

edited : I am posting small gif to describe my issue more 
[image: Gif of issue]

Comment: show the code related to the issue? Where r u hiding the navigaiton bar ? How you are coming back from fullscreenview ?

Comment: i given code how i pushing that CNContactViewConteoller and after push all thing handle by CNContactSore i don't do anything for that.

Comment: This is a known Apple bug apparently. See also: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973254/cncontactviewcontroller-forunknowncontact-unusable-destroys-interface
and https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/82793#82793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known Apple bug apparently.

you can find fixes for this at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289350/4734164