# CNContactViewController and SFSafariViewController on iOS cannot be used within a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cncontactviewcontroller

I have been trying to use `CNContactViewController` without success. I want to show a list of contacts (which I expected there to be a built-in VC for), then tap into the detail of that contact and have it displayed as in the Contacts or Phone built-in app. This doesn't seem to be possible, as pushing these new VCs seems to break the UI in weird ways, see below.

My main question is: **am I stuck re-creating the UI for this functionality myself, or are there known workarounds?**

This example uses a UINavigationController within UITabBarController:
[image: UINavigationController within UITabBarController]

Initial presentation works as expected:
[image: Initial presentation works as expected]

Tapping the "Share" button attempts to show a UIAlertController, which appears *behind* the tab bar, and also removes the UINavigationController's top bar:
[image: Tapping the share button breaks the whole thing]

This is similar to the issues faced in this question: [CNContactViewController forUnknownContact unusable, destroys interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973254/cncontactviewcontroller-forunknowncontact-unusable-destroys-interface)

Comment: File a bug report with Apple...

Comment: Yeah, that's kind-of a given, but I'm hoping to find a way to make my app work in the meantime.