# Open Add Contacts Page on Button Click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a button that, when pressed, will open the **Add Contacts Page of Phone Application**. And once the Done/Cancel button is pressed, it should come back to my Application. I know this is possible, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Apple address book programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1) will help you:

```
   ABNewPersonViewController *view = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
   view.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

   UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                              initWithRootViewController:view];
   [self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController
                    animated:YES];
```

**ABNewPersonViewController** is deprecated with iOS9. One should use CNContactViewController instead. Unfortunately there is a bug, refer to this thread ([CNContactViewController Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973254/cncontactviewcontroller-forunknowncontact-unusable-destroys-interface)).

```
  CNContactStore().requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) {ok, err in
        guard ok else {return} // only if access is granted
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let con = CNMutableContact()

            let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: con)
            unkvc.contactStore = CNContactStore()
            unkvc.delegate = self
            unkvc.allowsActions = false
            self.presentViewController(unkvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

and the delegate methods:

```
func contactViewController(vc: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWithContact con: CNContact?) 

func contactViewController(vc: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty prop: CNContactProperty) -> Bool
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys, it worked!
Is it possible to come back to my application after i press done/cancel button?

Comment: You defined your ViewController, where you present the `ABNewPersonViewController`, as delegate. Therefore you have to implement the delegate methods of this `ABNewPersonViewController`, like this one `unknownPersonViewController:didResolveToPerson:`

Comment: I just saw that with iOS9 this `ABNewPersonViewController` is deprecated. you should use CNContactViewController instead. I will provide some information my edited answer.

Comment: Im sorry I can't figure out what you just said. I am new to coding so it'll be really helpful for me if you could explain it.

Comment: that would be really nice @marc14

Comment: @SachinDinesh what information didn't you understand?

Comment: could you please share the exact code to do the process?

Comment: Please look at the link, which I posted in my answer and which is referring to another stackoverflow thread. There is a github link which contains an example Xcode project.

Comment: I think i found the answer:

(void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person