# "Create New Contact" and "Add to Existing Contact" for CNContactViewController()

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, cncontact

With ABAddressBook, when I wanted the user to be able to have the options of "Create New Contact" and "Add to Existing Contact" for a contact they hadn't seen before, I would create and present an `ABUnknownPersonViewController`.

I can find no way to replicate this functionality in the CNContacts framework. It seemed to me that `CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: contact)` could work, but unfortunately this only lets the user "Send Message" or "Share Contact."

**How can I allow a user to save the contact to their address book, either as a new contact or as part of an existing one, in CNContacts?**

```
func presentContact() {

    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts)

    switch status {
    case .Authorized: ()
    case .NotDetermined: requestAccess()
    case .Denied, .Restricted: accessDenied()
    }

    print("authorized? \(status == .Authorized)") //prints "authorized? true"

    let unknown = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: contact!)

    unknown.delegate = self

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unknown, animated: false)

}
```

*Even when I try to request access, the user still can't save the contact.*

Comment: Because you are not showing real code. Show your code! You are still leaving out all sorts of important pieces, and I can't tell whether that's because you don't know that you should do them or because you're just being lazy in pasting your code into Stack Overflow. What's `contact`? Show the line where you set `unknown`'s `contactStore`. Those things are all important. _SHOW. YOUR. REAL. CODE._

Comment: What important pieces am I still leaving out? `contact` is an arbitrary `CNContact` with any number of properties set. I'm not sure how that could have an effect on the action buttons not being shown. Everything is here except for `unknown`'s `contactStore` property being set, which turns out to be the problem. Thanks for your help. I'm sorry if I cut some corners in making a minimal reproducible example; I was trying to make it as simple and easy as possible to follow.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer—or the answer you posted, if it still existed—because setting `contactStore` properly did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You keep not showing *your* real code, so it's impossible to help you. So I've lost interest. I'll just show you *my* real code instead and leave you to study it and think about the difference between what I'm doing and what you're doing. Here's actual working code; go ye and do likewise:

```
let con = CNMutableContact()
con.givenName = "Johnny"
con.familyName = "Appleseed"
con.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(
    label: "woods", value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "555-123-4567")))
let unkvc = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: con)
unkvc.message = "He knows his trees"
unkvc.contactStore = CNContactStore()
unkvc.delegate = self
unkvc.allowsActions = false
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unkvc, animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: Beware, however, of the bug I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32973254/341994

Comment: What's posted above _really_, _actually_ is my real code. Line for line, word for word, that's what I have in one of my `.swift` files. Not setting `contactStore` was the problem; you did help me.

Comment: Worked for me !!

Comment: 'back' button doesnt show up ! Every other thing works fine. Can you give me a work around on how to show the back button. My App is hosed on this screen only.

Comment: @ZahurafzalMirza Because you are not inside a navigation controller.

Comment: Bro i am inside a navigation controller still the buttons didnt show up. However i ended up adding a left bar button item for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
CNPhoneNumber * number  = [[CNPhoneNumber alloc] initWithStringValue:@"1234567890"];
CNLabeledValue * labelValue = [[CNLabeledValue alloc]initWithLabel:CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile value:number];
NSMutableArray<CNLabeledValue *> *phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];
[phoneNumbers addObject:labelValue];
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];

controller.contactStore = store;
controller.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code will work for "Create New Contact", for "Add to Existing Contact" we will have to use CNContactPickerViewController

```
CNContactPickerViewController * picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
                                    picker.delegate = self;
                                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and the in the delegate method

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact
{
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    CNMutableContact *existingContact = [(CNMutableContact*)contact mutableCopy];
    CNPhoneNumber * number  = [[CNPhoneNumber alloc] initWithStringValue:@"1234567890"];
    CNLabeledValue * labelValue = [[CNLabeledValue alloc]initWithLabel:CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile value:number];
    NSMutableArray<CNLabeledValue *> *phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];
    [phoneNumbers addObject:labelValue];
    [phoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray:existingContact.phoneNumbers];
    existingContact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:existingContact];

    controller.contactStore = store;
    controller.delegate = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] animated:YES completion:nil];
    });

}
```

although it will show the Done button, instead of Update, but it will perform the functionality definitely as iPhone's default behaviour in Contacts App.

Comment: The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. Please post a Swift example. Thanks.

Comment: @Moritz to just have an idea of what to do, Objective-C code is enough, and as a developer its not a big deal to understand the code whether its in Swift or Objective-C, plus there are tools which can convert the code, so plz..

Comment: I just got through this, and shared what I have implemented recently, when i'll get some free time, I'll do that too.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing in your code is setting the `contactStore` property of your `unknown` variable to a handle of a `CNContactStore`.

```
[...]

unknown.contactStore = CNContactStore()

[...]
```