# Why top Navigation Bar disappear when do some action on the view using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, cncontact

I have `ViewController` which has one button to navigate to `CNContactViewController` every thing works good I can go back and press the button again and so on .But my problem when I do one action on the `CNContactViewController` which is `Share Contact` the top navigation bar will disappear and for sure I'll stuck in this view .. this is the code:

```
    @IBAction func dothis(sender: AnyObject) {

    let contact = CNMutableContact()
    contact.givenName = "first Name"
    contact.familyName = "Last Name"
    contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(
        label:"Mobile",
        value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"123456789")),
        CNLabeledValue(
            label:"Work Phone",
            value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"1234"))]

    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:"Work Email", value:"ex@whatever.com")
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]

    let controller = CNContactViewController (forContact: contact)
    controller.contactStore = self.store
    controller.allowsEditing = false

    controller.displayedPropertyKeys =
        [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey]

    self.navigationController?
        .pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}
```

Do I need to implement something more for share contact and other actions on the `CNContactViewController` ?

Notes:

1- All actions on contact card work good like `Call` or `Send Message` except `Share Contact` causing the problem.

2- When I compare the actions on my VC with the Contacts app I notice that the pop up options view of `Share Contact` comes over the navigation bar but in my app the options view come behind the navigation bar .

See Contacts app on the left and my app on the right :

[image: Contacts App here][image: My App]

My Project file : [Here](https://ufile.io/b5a05) it's small project

Comment: are you hidden the navigation bar in anywhere in your CNContactViewController

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is the only code I have , I made new project has one class which has this action to make sure the problem not in my old code

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the console? Your IBAction, do you also have a segue to the `CNContactViewController` in the storyboard?

Comment: @Fogmeister No errors showing on console + no segue in the storyboard

Comment: @fogmeister you can see the project in the question , only one VC and one class

Comment: Need a help please

Comment: I download your demo, and test it with Xcode 8,iOS 10.The navigation bar will reappear when you click cancel  button. Maybe you should  try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did update Xcode to version 8.0 with Swift 3 and the problem solved without changing the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33762209/3378099

Here is a non-elegant solution:

1. Create an new class extending UINavigationController
2. Assign it to your NavigationController in Storyboard
3. Override function `func setNavigationBarHidden(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)`

Reuploaded your project [here](https://ufile.io/23b08)

Comment: actually I got more problems than before

Comment: What problems do you have now?

Comment: UI problems , like when I press create new contact and pop up view came the cancel button doesn't work also when trying to send email to the contact email it will open the mail app but behind the top bar navigation and more ..