# CNContactPickerViewcontroller navigationBar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

how do i change the black bar to another color?

N.B this is a CNContactPickerViewcontroller...the first screen(list of contacts) looks fine but when i click on a contact to choose a specific contact property then the navigation bar turns black.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to set the Appearance of UINavigationBar to the color you want:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

And once you return to the previous ViewController (Maybe with `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`) you set it again to the previous color you were using.

I presented the Contact this way:

```
CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

// Create contact
CNMutableContact *contact = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
contact.givenName = @"Someone Name";

CNLabeledValue *contactPhoneNumber = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelHome value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@"Some number"]];
contact.phoneNumbers = @[contactPhoneNumber];

CNContactViewController *contactController = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForUnknownContact:contact];
contactController.navigationItem.title = @"Add to contacts";
contactController.contactStore = store;
contactController.delegate = self;


[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};

[self.navigationController pushViewController:contactController animated:YES];
```

Once the contactController is Dismissed the `viewWillAppear` is called and you can add there the color restore depending on your needs:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

}

Comment: Okay, because my experience is that you don't get control over the second CNContactPickerViewcontroller screen this way (because it isn't part of your app).

Comment: Yes, sounds similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40600727/341994 — thanks.

Comment: if you do not use UINavigationBar.appearance() in you project that solution will confuse nav bar colors across whole app.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by changing the backgroundColor of the navbar subviews after a delay, not pretty, but it's good enough for me:

```
CNContactViewController *vc = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:contact];
vc.delegate = self;

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (UIView *view in [vc.navigationController.navigationBar subviews]) {
        view.tintColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
});

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```